# MSMessages Extension and NSUserDefaults in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, swift3

I am working on an MSMessages Extension in iOS 10 using Swift 3.0. I am trying to save some items in NSUserDefaults but no matter what I do I always get nil.

```
 // get the data out of the nsuserdefaults 
        guard let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.company.quickresponse") else {
            fatalError("Unable to create UserDefaults")
        }

         var responsesData = userDefaults.data(forKey: "Responses")

        if responsesData == nil {
            self.responses = [QuickResponse]()
        }
        else {
            self.responses = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: responsesData!) as? [QuickResponse]
        }

        // add the response to the collection
        self.responses.append(response)
        // archive the collection 
        responsesData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.responses)

        // persist the collection in the nsuserdefaults
        userDefaults.set(responsesData, forKey: "Responses")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
```

The following line:

```
 var responsesData = userDefaults.data(forKey: "Responses")
```

is always returning nil. What am I doing wrong? I tried the default NSUserDefaults and it gave the same result then I tried with the suiteName and same result. The app groups is enabled in the Capabilities tab.

Comment: As always, **do not** use `valueForKey` in `NSUserDefaults`. There is a dedicated method `dataforKey`

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code with data (updated in original code above) but I still get nil when it reads from the key "Responses".

Comment: @johndoe Are you trying that on the simulator or with a real device?

Comment: I am trying that on the simulator. It is iOS 10 Beta so I am not running on the real device.

Comment: I had the same problem with my app when running on the simulator it would never persist and on the real device it was working fine. Try reseting the simulator contents and settings